# Called failed in Linphone iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, voip, linphone

I have successfully compiled (according to readme file provided by Linphone) and installed Linphone client on simulator and it is successfully registered to local sip server. But it shows "`Call failed, Cannot call xxxxxxxxx, Reason was: no response`" if I dial any number. I checked captured packet using WireShark, it only shows register sip request, but no invite request.

Any idea whats wrong? Kindly share your valuable knowledge on that.

---

Comment: you are trying to use it in simulator. Does it work on a phone itself?

Comment: @MZimmerman6  Yes, I am trying to use it in simulator. I do not have valid provisioning certificate to test on device right now. I will manage soon and let you know result.

Answer (score 0):

Because may be you are dialling wrong number OR the number you are dialling is not yet registered on your **SIP server.**

You should also log in with other number to make call. Means on different PC run linphone on simulator or device. Then try to make call.